# Create a new collection by changing the view of data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have mongo Employee collection with department information as a nested document.

Example:

```
{
    "_id": 7934,
    "ename": "MILLER",
    "job": "CLERK",
    "mgr": "7782",
    "hiredate": ISODate("1982-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
    "sal": 1300,
    "department": {
        "deptno": 10,
        "dname": "ACCOUNTING",
        "loc": "NEW YORK"
    }
}
```

Now I have to create a new collection by using Employee collection to have department information as root with an array of employees of that department.

Example:

```
{
    "_id": 10,
    "deptno": 10,
    "dname": "ACCOUNTING",
    "loc": "NEW YORK",
    "employees": [{
        "ename": "MILLER",
        "job": "CLERK",
        "mgr": "7782",
        "hiredate": ISODate("1982-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
        "sal": 1300
    }, {
        "ename": "JOHN"...
    }]
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried in order to achieve that so far? And what exactly does not work for you that you need to understand? Please understand that at present your "question" reads more like a "work order" than an actual question. People are generally happy to help when you show some effort and present a point you might be "stuck on". But people are less happy when you essentially leave instructions to do your job for you, for free. A little effort goes a long way.

Comment: db.employee.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$department.deptno",deptno:{$first:"$department.deptno"},dname:{$first:"$department.dname"},loc:{$first:"$department.loc"},employees:{$addToSet:{"$empno"}}}, {$out : "department"}]);   I have tried this. But employees set is coming as empty.. I am not sure is grouping is a solution or not

Comment: Probably empty because your data has no such field `empno`. Considering each employee is probably already unique the `$addToSet` is probably a bit redundant, but there might be another operator to construct an array. Not sure? Well are you not "grouping the employees under the distinct departments?" Because that's what it looks like you are asking. With just a little more effort you should get there.

Comment: Yes Neil, I requirement is to group users based on deptno. $sum i am able to get no of employees in a particular group. But i need employee details in the array. When i use $[collection name] or $[_id] is giving null

Comment: Your question does not show an `empno` field. You possibly mean `_id`. You need to read the actual data rather than just read the job instruction your manager gave you.

Comment: @Madhuprathap Please update the question with what you have tried with your analysis, It would help other developers in the long run. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$department.deptno",
            "department":{
                $first:"$department"
            },
            "employees":{
                $push:"$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot:{
            "newRoot":{
                $mergeObjects:[
                    "$department",
                    {
                        "employees":"$employees"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "employees.department":0
        }
    },
    {
        $out:"department"
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : 7934,
    "ename" : "MILLER",
    "job" : "CLERK",
    "mgr" : "7782",
    "hiredate" : ISODate("1982-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
    "sal" : 1300,
    "department" : {
        "deptno" : 10,
        "dname" : "ACCOUNTING",
        "loc" : "NEW YORK"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : 7935,
    "ename" : "MECHANIC",
    "job" : "CEO",
    "mgr" : "7700",
    "hiredate" : ISODate("1982-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
    "sal" : 9999999999999,
    "department" : {
        "deptno" : 10,
        "dname" : "ACCOUNTING",
        "loc" : "NEW YORK"
    }
}
```

**Collection: department**

```
{
    "deptno" : 10,
    "dname" : "ACCOUNTING",
    "loc" : "NEW YORK",
    "employees" : [
        {
            "_id" : 7934,
            "ename" : "MILLER",
            "job" : "CLERK",
            "mgr" : "7782",
            "hiredate" : ISODate("1982-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
            "sal" : 1300
        },
        {
            "_id" : 7935,
            "ename" : "MECHANIC",
            "job" : "CEO",
            "mgr" : "7700",
            "hiredate" : ISODate("1982-01-22T18:30:00Z"),
            "sal" : 9999999999999
        }
    ]
}
```